# Drupal7 wiki_commons editing error

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commons

I've installed wiki_commons on my drupal7, and i have en error whe im trying to edit wiki node:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property
>   field_target_nodes. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line
>   340)

Comment: Also having this error